# How to generate random vector in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I want to generate random vectors with norm 1 in Spark.

Since the vector could be very large, I want it to be distributed, And since data in RDD has no order, I want to store the vector in the form of RDD[(Int, Double)], because I also need to use this vector to do some matrix-vector multiplication.

So how could I generate this kind of vector?

Here is my plan for now:

```
val v = normalRDD(sc, n, NUM_NODE)
val mod = GetMod(v)       // Get the modularity of v
val res = v.map(x => x / mod)
val arr:Array[Double] = res.toArray()

var tuples = new List[(Int, Double)]()
for (i <- 0 to (arr.length - 1)) {
  tuples = (i, arr(i)) :: tuples
}
// Get the entries and length of the vector.
entries = sc.parallelize(tuples)
length = arr.length
```

I think it not elegant enough because it goes through a "distributed -> single node -> distributed" process.

Is there any way better? Thanks:D

Comment: do you want a random rdd whose norm is 1 or a normally distributed rdd?

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao I think I just want  a random rdd whose norm is 1. normally distributed is ok according to my code:D

Comment: I see. I posted my code below. Format of final answer : RDD[(Int, Double)], randomly generated and norm is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import scala.util.Random
import scala.math.sqrt

val n = 5 // insert length of your array here
val randomRDD = sc.parallelize(for (i <- 0 to n) yield (i, Random.nextDouble))
val norm = sqrt(randomRDD.map(x => x._2 * x._2).sum())
val finalRDD = randomRDD.mapValues(x => x/norm)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/Vector.html#random(int,%20scala.util.Random)) function to generate a random vector, then you can normalise it by dividing each element on the `sum()` of the vector, or by using a [normalizer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#normalizer).